# Unable to Run PySpark Example

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i'm trying to run an example of recommendation system i got from an online class
however when i try to run the line

```
model = als.fit(train)
```

i get the following error

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e3ce1dc2b89b> in <module>
----> 1 model = als.fit(train)

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    286 
    287     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 288         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    289         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    290         return self._copyValues(model)

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    283         """
    284         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 285         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    286 
    287     def _fit(self, dataset):

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1158         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1159         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1161 
   1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    321             else:
    322                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 5 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:837)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:835)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:835)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1838)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1751)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1924)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1357)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1923)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:572)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1988)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1162)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$.train(ALS.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.fit(ALS.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.fit(ALS.scala:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

anyone know what might be happening here? perhaps a faulty installation somewhere?

EDIT: Since i was asked to show the rest of the code

```
import findspark 
findspark.init("C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7")
import pyspark 
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameNaFunctions 
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit 
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer  
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('sistemi di raccomandazione').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('/Users/Andrea/ml-latest-small/ratings.csv',
                   header = True, inferSchema = True)
df.show()
df.columns
df.describe().show()
train, test = df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS
als = ALS(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01, userCol="userId", 
          itemCol="movieId", 
          ratingCol="rating", 
          coldStartStrategy="drop")
model = als.fit(train)
```

the dataset is the one from MovieLens

EDIT2: trying to run the code suggested by sid_k give me the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2e64a86f2857> in <module>
      7 sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
      8 load_data=sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
----> 9 load_data.foreach(print())

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in foreach(self, f)
    795                 f(x)
    796             return iter([])
--> 797         self.mapPartitions(processPartition).count()  # Force evaluation
    798 
    799     def foreachPartition(self, f):

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in count(self)
   1054         3
   1055         """
-> 1056         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
   1057 
   1058     def stats(self):

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in sum(self)
   1045         6.0
   1046         """
-> 1047         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
   1048 
   1049     def count(self):

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
    919         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
    920         # to the final reduce call
--> 921         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    922         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
    923 

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in collect(self)
    822         """
    823         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 824             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    825         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    826 

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1158         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1159         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1161 
   1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    321             else:
    322                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 229, in main
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 224, in process
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 362, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 795, in processPartition
    f(x)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 229, in main
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 224, in process
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 362, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 795, in processPartition
    f(x)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: You need to provide more code as the issue seems to be with the parameters you pass into the model (```Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps,``` ), not with the call to .fit itself.

Comment: added the rest of the code, however like i said this is an example from a course i'm following so shouldn't the code by itself be correct?

Comment: You can see 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable'

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux ? do you have Java and python installed ?

Comment: i'm on windows 7, i have python installed but i'm trying to run this code on an anaconda installation, i have java installed

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that `findspark` is installed using `pip install findspark` in `CMD` and environment variables are properly set for `spark`. In Jupyter add below lines and then execute the code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
load_data=sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
load_data.collect()
```

Comment: i did install findspark by using pip install findspark... if i try to run that suggested code, i get another error

Comment: i don't know how to add code in comments, so i edited it in the main request

Comment: Just check once again. I have edited the last line of the code and it works fine for me. If it doesn't work post the entire code you are trying to execute rather than just posting the error

Comment: your example now works, but i still get an error when trying to execute "model = als.fit(train), something along the lines of "could not establish connection, persistent rejection of the target computer"

Comment: I am not in to ml so won't be able to help you with that. Sorry! I just made sure that your spark is working properly.